# Changing variable cluster on shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet.markercluster

I have a doubt regarding the cluster agrupation on shiny of R. I have a terrorist dataset I am working with and when I use this code:

```
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
leaflet(terrorist) %>% addTiles() %>% addLabelOnlyMarkers(
  label=~as.character(terrorist$nkill),
  clusterId = terrorist$nkill,
  clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(),
  labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T,
                              direction = 'auto'))
```

I get a number in the label related to the number of accidents in that part of the map, like if it were making groups by number of rows on each part and I want a data which comes from a column called nkill.

Here you have a sample of the dataset in case it may help you. Thanks in advance.

```
head(terrorist[c('eventid','latitude','longitude','nkill')])

       eventid  latitude longitude nkill
1 201406150063 34.596934  43.67948  1500
2 200109110004 40.712784 -74.00594  1383
3 200109110005 40.712784 -74.00594  1382
4 199404130008 -1.932787  30.33246  1180
5 201406100042 36.399408  42.96361   670
6 200403210001 27.959441  84.89590   518
```